# Windows 6.5 and Silverlight

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

Does Windows Phone 6.5 Support XNA and Silverlight?

Comment: Your question references Windows Phone 6.5, but you've tagged with with a Windows Phone 7 tag. Which are you looking for?

Comment: that's what i was thinking as well!

Comment: I really want Windows Phone 6.5

Comment: my god, you users of stackoverflow are so serious
you know that, so asnwer, that's what I do when I get time :P

Comment: my god you certainly have time to complain but not accept any answers :P

Comment: I'm sorry, its just because i'm already stressed with this site.

Comment: anyway, I edited and corrected the tag.

Comment: Don't get stressed. Lifes too short. I just wanted to make sure I answered the right question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 supports development with XNA or Silverlight.

Windows Mobile 6.5 is an operating system which doesn't support either.

Devices running Windows Mobile 6.5 were advertised to consumers as being "Windows Phones" but they are not the same as "Windows Phone 7". Application development is different for the two and applications developed for one are not compatible with the other.

Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question you asked (does windows phone 6.5 support XNA and Silverlight) is: NO.

The answer to the question you inferred by tagging this question with Win Phone 7 tags (does windows phone 7 support XNA and Silverlight) is: YES

Both of these are easy answers to discover if you copy those two questions and paste them into a search engine. This will give you more information about the level of support and toolsets.

Comment: mm..I think I searched in another language than English.
thank you.